# C# Socket works locally but not remotely

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, server

I have a C# Client and a seperate Server application. When i execute both on the same machine, im able to connect to the server. However, when i try to connect to my server remotely it always ends in a timeout. I use the port 139 and I tried running the server application on mulitple machines. I have tried it on a server that is open to the public, my private PC with my router forwarding this port to the PC, as well as laptops in the same network. 
I have always checked if the machine the server is running on is listening on the port using netstat -an and made exceptions in the firewall on all of them.
The code I use on the client to connect to the server:

```
 static IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");               
 static IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];                             
 static IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);                       
 static Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,                          
     SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

static private void ConnectToServer()
    {
        try
        {
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                   new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.ToString());
        }
    }

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.  
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.  
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The code I use to accept the connection on the server:

```
 static IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
 static IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
 static IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 139);
 static Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                Console.WriteLine("Listening on: " + ipAddress);
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        allDone.Set();
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }
```

As I said this works flawlessly when both client and server application are executed on the same PC. If however they are on different machines the client gets a timout error within a couple of seconds.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Use `IPAddress.Any` instead of the ip of your system.. you're only listening on loopback

Comment: Try using a port number above 1000, preferably above 10,000.  Port number 1 to 1000 are mostly reserved for specific protocols and often are blocked by by firewalls and virus checkers.  I usually recommend above 10000 since lower number may already be in use.  Pick a number that most other people will not pick.

Comment: Yes, `IPAddress.Any` and any port number above 1000 (or any available port) should be fine and might solve your problem, just make sure you are able to ping the server IP from client machine and vice versa.

Comment: Which expression should i replace with IPAdress.Any?

Comment: In this `static IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port); ` change `ipAddress` to `IPAddress.Any` and on client code `static IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 139);` change the `ipAddress` to the Server IP address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` port number will remain same on both anyways. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: remoteEp is on the client and localEndPoint is on  the server. So when I try static IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAdress.Any,11000) I get an error:
0x80004005: When attempting to use the pointer argument of a call, an invalid pointer address was found (translated via google translate since the error was in german.)